# CKeditor is still parsing CSS Clasess after removing stylesheetparser plugin in Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates, ckeditor, django-admin

I was trying to install Ckeditor in my Django Admin Interface. I want to write myself in html code. But allow other users to use Ckeditor to write the html code. If i open a post from admin. Ckeditor removes the classes of all the tags. According the Ckeditor documentation available on:

https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation

I should remove the plugin stylesheetparser by configuring the Ckeditor. I did that but still the Ckeditor the removing the Classes from the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will add to your CKEditor config

```
config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*)';
```

It will allowed all classes for all tags.

You can read more here

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter